# Plus between digits in order to make a true statement

Tags: c#, math

I need to put pluses (+) between digits of a large number, and to move over the all options, in order to get a true expression or a true statement: (C#)

> *Example:*
>   if I have---> **130=1612345** 
>   I need it to be---> **130=1+61+23+45**

I tried it with arrays, fors, and so..

[I don't care about efficiency]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that does what Jeroen Boschma has described:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "130=1612345";

        string[] inputs = input.Split("=".ToCharArray());
        if (inputs.Length == 2)
        {
            string strSum = inputs[0].Trim();
            string strDigits = inputs[1].Trim();
            int sum, values;
            if (int.TryParse(strSum, out sum) && int.TryParse(strDigits, out values))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
                List<string> solutions = FindEquation(sum, values);
                Console.WriteLine("Solutions Found: " + solutions.Count.ToString());
                for(int i = 0; i < solutions.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Solution #" + (i + 1).ToString() + ": " + solutions[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Press [Enter] to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<string> FindEquation(int sum, int values)
    {
        List<string> solutions = new List<string>();

        string binary;
        string[] addends;
        int iterationSum;
        StringBuilder iteration = new StringBuilder();
        char[] digits = values.ToString().ToCharArray();
        int possibilities = (int)Math.Pow((double)2, (double)(digits.Length - 1));
        for(int i=0; i < possibilities; i++)
        {
            binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(digits.Length - 1, '0');
            iteration.Clear();
            for(int j=0;j<digits.Length; j++)
            {
                iteration.Append(digits[j]);
                if((j < (digits.Length -1)) && (binary.Substring(j, 1) == "1"))
                {
                    iteration.Append("+");
                }
            }

            addends = iteration.ToString().Split("+".ToCharArray());
            iterationSum = 0;
            foreach(string addend in addends)
            {
                iterationSum = iterationSum + int.Parse(addend);
            }
            if (iterationSum == sum)
            {
                solutions.Add(sum.ToString() + "=" + iteration.ToString());
            }
        }
        return solutions;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Input: 130=1612345
Solutions Found: 1
Solution #1: 130=1+61+23+45

Press [Enter] to exit...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a C# related question, but your looking for an algorithm. In your example the '1612345' contains 7 digits, this means that in between there are 6 places where a + can possibly be present. So for N digits, N-1 possible plusses, and to count them all you have 2^(N-1) possibilities.

So make a for loop which counts from 0 (no plusses) to 2^(N-1)-1 (all plusses present). For each plus to test if it is present you do a bit-test on the for-loop variable (each plus corresponds with a bit-position of the for-loop variable). Then you can check if the current combination gives a valid sum.

Comment: Giving an answer to such a poor question is discouraged here--though it is good that you stuck to just a broad algorithm rather than code. Please avoid answering such questions in the future.

Comment: and @Rory , please respect other's questions, I tried to do it, and my solution was terrible, so I asked for help, even that my question is "such poor", your are disrespect the people here and their problems. what looks trivial for ones, can be really hard for others, :(

Comment: @TiranArazi: I have no problem with beginners asking questions to easy problems--I have answered such questions, and in fact I have answered a question very much like yours. I do have a problem with people asking questions here without showing any work of their own. For example, you stated "I tried it with arrays, fors, and so.." but you did not show any evidence of that claim. Please show some of the code you attempted, even if it failed, to show that you are not just dumping your homework on us.

Comment: how did you get to 2^(n-1) possibilities? @JeroenBoschma

Comment: @Tiran: each possible plus corresponds with a bit of the for-loop variable. So if you have 6 possible plusses, then your for-loop variable must be 6 bits and count from 000000 to 111111 (binary) to evaluate all possibilities which are 2^6 different values. See the solution of Idle_Mind who made the effort for coding this solution, I was too lazy...

Comment: Thanks :) @JeroenBoschma